# JavaScript to show in label each selected value of drop downs in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to print next to each dropdown of my table the selected value.
I used the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

        $("select").change(function() {
            var str = "";
            $(".item-number option:selected").each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).attr('label'))
                    str = $(this).attr('label');
                else
                    str = "Description shows up here ";
            });
            $(".item-name").text(str);
        }).trigger('change');

    });

</script>
```

Whenever I change one of the drop downs value the labels of all the table becomes the same.
Is there a way to change only the label next to the drop down I change the selected option?

[image]

The HTML code of the table is:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="status[]" class="item-number">
       <option value="1" label="Active">Active</option>
       <option value="0" label="Deactive" selected="selected">Deactive</option>
       <option value="delete" label="Delete">Delete</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <select name="status[]" class="item-number">
         <option value="1" label="Active">Active</option>
         <option value="0" label="Deactive" selected="selected">Deactive</option>
         <option value="delete" label="Delete">Delete</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select name="status[]" class="item-number">
           <option value="1" label="Active">Active</option>
           <option value="0" label="Deactive" selected="selected">Deactive</option>
           <option value="delete" label="Delete">Delete</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Please include the actual relevant rendered HTML MArkup your code interacts with, add a code snippet through the code snippet feature on the question editor and make a working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You should update your question with required HTML so that some one can help you....

Comment: @Mamun what do you mean? I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to fit your html.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select").change(function() {
      // No need to loop through all the selects each time, since you can only change one value at a time.      
      var str = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('label') || "Description shows up here";
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".item-name").html(str);
  }).trigger('change');
  
});
```

```css
table td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
select,
table td{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="status[]" class="item-number">
       <option value="1" label="Active">Active</option>
       <option value="0" label="Deactive" selected="selected">Deactive</option>
       <option value="delete" label="Delete">Delete</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <select name="status[]" class="item-number">
         <option value="1" label="Active">Active</option>
         <option value="0" label="Deactive" selected="selected">Deactive</option>
         <option value="delete" label="Delete">Delete</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="status[]" class="item-number">
           <option value="1" label="Active">Active</option>
           <option value="0" label="Deactive" selected="selected">Deactive</option>
           <option value="delete" label="Delete">Delete</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I print the label with this code:
<td><span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span></td>
The code does not work, but can i change the "span" into something else and have the same results?

Comment: If you have html element in your string, don't use `.text()`, change it to `.html()` instead. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: This doesn't work :( 
I change it to .html(str) and nothing changes

Comment: This code works correct only for the last <tr> of the table

Comment: Are `<td>` and `<span class="item-name">` exists in the table when you change the drop down?

Comment: I created a JSFiddle. Take a look and Let me know which part of the code is not working for you?